# How to take the derivative of this

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got this problem in school, but do not know how to answer it, does anyone know how?

How would you take the derivative of 
$$\frac{a}{\cos\ \theta} + \frac{b}{\sin\ \theta}$$
and then set the answer to $0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to find the derivative?

Comment: Just curious. May I ask if you are doing a physics problem involving something like the Coulumb force or gravitational force?

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting as
$$a \sec\theta+b\csc\theta$$
Taking derivative
$$a \sec\theta \tan\theta -b \csc\theta \cot\theta$$
equating to zero
$$a \sec\theta \tan\theta =b \csc\theta \cot\theta$$
or 
$$\tan^3\theta =b/a$$